# Websocket connection not working on Safari (MacOS), all browsers (IOS devices) but works fine on all browsers in Windows and Android

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket, safari

I have a chatbot application that uses Spring Boot at the backend and ReactJS for the UI. This application works fine on Windows Desktop/Laptop ( Chrome/Firefox/Edge) but doesn't work on Safari in MacOS and doesn't work on all the browsers in IOS devices.

Error I get in backend logs :

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The extension [x-webkit-deflate-frame] is not supported at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.TransformationFactory.create(TransformationFactory.java:48)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil.createTransformations(UpgradeUtil.java:268)*

Error I get from Safari inspection:

[Error] Web Socket connection to 'ws://......' failed: Unexpected response code: 500
[Error] Socket encountered error:  – undefined – "Closing socket"
(anonymous function) (main.e034c8dc.chunk.js:1:167988)

Any solution would be really helpful, long time with this issue now.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider putting error messages in code blocks, that makes it easier to read :)